# Shadow of a frame remains

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting

The setup below leaves a shadow of a frame around the input. How can I make the box blend totally with the background?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable}

\newtcblisting
{internal}
{text only,
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  fontupper=\sffamily,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  halign=left,
  fontupper=\small\sffamily,
  left=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{internal}
\LaTeX
\end{internal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating your example with the following parameter should do it.

```
boxrule=-1pt
```

[image]